# karate: Accept = 'application/xml' header not working as expected

Tags: karate

Even after setting the header, Accept = 'application/xml', when i am logging the response, it is showing json. My request is xml and i want to compare this xml request with the xml response. Can someone help.

```
Given url testUrl
    And header Accept = 'application/xml'
    Then retry until responseStatus == 200
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    * karate.log("created: %s", response)
```

Comment: quite likely that internally everything is fine and it is XML. if you still feel there is a bug follow this process, else I personally think no one can help you: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Ok i got the issue, actually i have my headers defined in karate-config.js where it is set application/json. Now actually i want to overwrite that for this particular scenario. Is it possible to do that?..looks like this(And header Accept = 'application/xml') is not working

Comment: ok, answer is in the linked answer, closed as duplicate